# Migration issue with trying to change attributes using gsub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, gsub, sti

I have a table called items.  I want to change the description attribute (it's a text attribute) for 9 of the objects.  Specifically, these objects are a subclass to Item -- called Juice.  So the items table is STI.  Here's a sample description of the item:

*Boost all payouts by **20%**.*

Now, when I try to run the following migration, I can't get the dang description to update.  Any ideas? (Rails version is 2.3.11.)

```
class ModifyItemJuiceDescription < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    juices = Juice.all

    Juice.transaction do
      for j in juices do
        puts "Juice description is: #{j.description}."
        j.description.gsub!('payouts', 'winnings')
        puts "Juice description will be saved as: #{j.description}."
        j.save!
        puts "Juice description is now: #{j.description}."
        puts "======================================================"
      end
    end

  end

  def self.down
    juices = Juice.all

    Juice.transaction do
      for j in juices do
        puts "Juice description is: #{j.description}."
        j.description.gsub!('winnings', 'payouts')
        puts "Juice description will be saved as: #{j.description}."
        j.save!
        puts "Juice description is now: #{j.description}."
        puts "======================================================"
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hunch that `j.description` returns a copy of the string, not the actual structure that maps to the database; The gsub! call changes the wrong object.

Try `j.description = j.description.gsub(...)`